# how to update a table based on select statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

hello i have a table has this data

```
T1:
Id start_date end_date flag
1  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
3  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
2  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
3  11-Mar-21  11-Jan-20 Y
```

what i want is to get the older start dates foreach id and make their flag to N
i want my output to be like that

```
T1:
Id start_date end_date flag
1  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
3  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 N
2  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
3  11-Mar-21  11-Jan-20 Y
```

i tried this sql statement

```
update
T1
set
flag='N'
where
Id
in
(select *
from T1
where start_date not in
(select MAX(start_date)as maxm from T1 group by T1.id) and Flag='Y');
```

but the problem is it takes all records contain id and update them to N
it gaves me this output

```
T1:
Id start_date end_date flag
1  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
3  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 N
2  11-Jan-20  11-Jan-20 Y
3  11-Mar-21  11-Jan-20 N
```

Comment: And when someone updates/inserts/deletes table data, you will have to do this again? I'd recommend a view instead, will always be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `merge`.

**Before:**

```
SQL> select * from t1 order by id, start_date;

        ID START_DAT END_DATE  F
---------- --------- --------- -
         1 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 Y
         2 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 Y
         3 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 Y
         3 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 Y
         3 11-Mar-21 11-Jan-20 Y
```

**Update flag:**

```
SQL> merge into t1 a
  2  using (select b.id,
  3                b.start_date,
  4                row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.start_date desc) rn
  5         from (select distinct t.id,
  6                               t.start_date
  7               from t1 t
  8              ) b
  9        ) x
 10  on (a.id = x.id and
 11      a.start_date = x.start_date
 12     )
 13  when matched then update set
 14    a.flag = 'N'
 15    where x.rn > 1;

2 rows merged.
```

**After:**

```
SQL> select * from t1 order by id, start_date;

        ID START_DAT END_DATE  F
---------- --------- --------- -
         1 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 Y
         2 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 Y
         3 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 N
         3 11-Jan-20 11-Jan-20 N
         3 11-Mar-21 11-Jan-20 Y
```

Comment: it gaves me this error:
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Comment: Looks like there are duplicates in your original table (and that's not contained in sample data you posted). I modified answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *view* the output above, you could actually use a select query:

```sql
SELECT Id, start_date, end_date,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM tgt_parent t2
           WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id AND
                 t2.start_date > t1.start_date
      ) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS flag
FROM tgt_parent;
```